abap MM01 get class for material
I am working on an enhancement in transaction MM01. I need to perform different actions depending on a class assigned to created material. Does anybody know where can I find an information about the class of the material that is being saved?
My enhancement is located in the include LMGMMF2J of program SAPLMGMM if that helps.
I looked for some information in the internet, but I found nothing about this case.
thanks in advance

To get the material's class, use the function module BAPI_OBJCL_GETCLASSES. The parameters you need to pass are:
OBJECTKEY_IMP    <material_number>
OBJECTTABLE_IMP  MARA
CLASSTYPE_IMP    001 

The BAPI will return all classes assigned to the material, it can be more than one.
If you need additional information from the classification (i.e. characteristics and their values), call afterwards function module BAPI_OBJCL_GETDETAIL.
You can also read the assigned classes for the material directly from KLAH, KSSK tables, but calling the BAPIs provided by SAP is a preferred way as they handle a lot of special cases.
I wrote some code to show the usage of the mentioned possibilities:
" sample variable of the material number type and value
DATA: lv_matnr TYPE matnr VALUE '000000000071006094'.

WRITE: / |Material classification for { lv_matnr }|.

SELECT class FROM klah
  LEFT JOIN kssk ON klah~clint = kssk~clint
WHERE kssk~objek = @lv_matnr
  AND klah~klart = '001'
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_klah).

LOOP AT lt_klah ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_klah>).
   WRITE: / |{ <fs_klah>-class }|.
ENDLOOP.


DATA: lt_class  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapi1003_alloc_list,
      lt_return TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapiret2.

CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_OBJCL_GETCLASSES'
  EXPORTING
    objectkey_imp   = CONV objnum( lv_matnr )
    objecttable_imp = 'MARA'
    classtype_imp   = '001'
  TABLES
    alloclist       = lt_class
    return          = lt_return.

IF NOT ( line_exists( lt_return[ type = 'E' ] ) OR line_exists( lt_return[ type = 'A' ] ) ).
  LOOP AT lt_class ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_class>).
    WRITE: / |{ <fs_class>-classnum }|.

    DATA: lt_values_num  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapi1003_alloc_values_num,
          lt_values_char TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapi1003_alloc_values_char,
          lt_values_curr TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapi1003_alloc_values_curr.

    CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_OBJCL_GETDETAIL'
      EXPORTING
        objectkey       = CONV objnum( iv_matnr )
        objecttable     = <fs_class>-objtyp
        classnum        = <fs_class>-classnum
        classtype       = <fs_class>-classtype
      TABLES
        allocvaluesnum  = lt_values_num
        allocvalueschar = lt_values_char
        allocvaluescurr = lt_values_curr
        return          = lt_return.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.

